# MySQL Store Procedure con transacciones devuelve Updated Rows '0' ¿por qué? - DBeaver

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, transacciones

trabajo con transacciones en MySQL quiero simplemente un UPDATE, el UPDATE funciona sin problemas, pero requiero saber el número de filas afectas, en gestor DBeaver me devuelve: 'Updated Rows': 0 más sin embargo si tengo la fila afectada.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dwitadmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `goworkers`.`sp_CandidatoCV_Upload`(
    IN p_Id INT,
    IN p_URL TEXT   
)
BEGIN

    start transaction;
        update 
            candidatos 
        set 
            curriculum_url = p_URL 
        where 
            id_candidato = p_Id;
    commit;
END
```

Anexo la salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí, en eso tienes razón, he removido el rollback, pero aún así no consigo que me devuelva el mensaje de updated rows

Comment: Pero ahora actualiza las filas que vos queres?

Comment: Sí, siempre me actualiza, simplemente no consigo devolver el 'mensaje' de filas actualizadas o afectadas

Comment: Perfecto. Tal vez sea un tema del motor particular de mysql o de al administrador de base de datos que usas para ejecutar eso. Aclara esos puntos, a ver si alguien sabe. Y usa el boton [edit], aclara todo eso. ademas de sacar el rollback que confunde...